# Mapping trapezoid to rectangle?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, mapping

How can I map a trapezoid to a rectangle? 
Do you have any AS3.0 code about mapping? Or a formula for mapping?

Comment: are you seeking to get the same area in both shapes? the AS3 CasaLib has some useful methods to convert a number in one coordinate space to the relative number in another coordinate space - might be useful - http://as3.casalib.org/docs/org_casalib_util_NumberUtil.html#map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not quite sure what you mean by mapping.

in case it might help, a homography ( http://en.nicoptere.net/?p=59 ) allows you to map a quadrilateral to another quadrilateral.

if you want to perform a texture extraction, a (much) faster way to do that is available here:
http://wonderfl.net/c/vbla

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to break up the rectangle into triangles, the more triangles you have the smoother the transform looks.

Example: http://www.blackcj.com/blog/2009/06/24/image-distortion-and-tapering-in-actionscript/